# Is there any good source of Hungary's legislative statistics?

Tags: legislative-process, statistics, hungary

Specifically, I am interested in figuring out the following pieces of information:

- How many times have the parliament voted on legislative acts since the Orban government since 2010;
- How many acts have been passed since then (potentially, how many sections of acts total);
- How many times did the MP's of the governing coalition vote against their coalition;
- How many votes have been cast by the coalition;
- How many of them were for and against or absentee ballots relative to the coalitions bills;
- How many MP's have ever cast any votes against the coalition in this period; and
- How many times did they cast such votes avg., med.?

Is there a citable database of any of the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some basic statistics in English can be found [here](https://www.parlament.hu/en/web/house-of-the-national-assembly/bills-submitted-and-adopted-broken-down-by-submitter). I think it includes the answers at least for your first two questions.

More detailed summary of each year are published on the webpage of the Assembly in Hungarian. [Here](https://www.parlament.hu/documents/10181/56582/ADATOK+v%C3%A9gleges+2021.pdf/dd88534e-0162-57b7-c746-08d69fb73f8e?t=1645451125669) is the most recent.

Comment: This looks great! Though The website is not GDPR compliant, and you can’t opt out, maybe it could be noted in the answer. Any ways, I’ll definitely skim though them in detail.